# What tests to be done in annual checkup after 50 years of age?

Tags: prevention

What tests should one get done annually/regularly after the age of 50 years? For example blood test for hemoglobin, blood sugar and kidney function, ECG, chest X-ray, PAP smear for women, bone density test, etc. Are all these really needed? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I am not saying these tests should be done. I have just given examples. I am asking which tests should be done on a regular basis after the age of 50 years. Or there is no need for an annual/regular checkup after this or any other age? Many organizations have a policy of annual checkups/testing of their employees.

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.  http://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think this question - containing a down-voted answer - is too broad, actually. Probably much better to just pick an organ system and leave it at that.

Comment: I have updated answer, i had some information wrong.

Comment: Both of those papers acknowledge that in the majority of cases, there is no medical need for annual screening. What are you adding to your *question*? It looks like you're trying to turn it into an answer. If that's the case, why don't you just post the answer? Then it can be vetted like all other answers.

Comment: I will update my question and post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Today's issue of New England Journal of Medicine (15th October, 2015) discusses the pros and cons of having annual screening:

[Improving Value in Health Care — Against the Annual Physical](http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJMp1507485)

[Toward Trusting Therapeutic Relationships — In Favor 
of the Annual Physical](http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJMp1508270)

Hence, there are 2 approaches:

1. There is no need for annual checkup, though healthy practices should be followed and early symptoms should not be ignored.
2. Majority of patients and physicians feel annual checkups should be there and one third of adults in USA get them done. Following simple tests can be done on an annual basis:

   - Annual consultation with general practitioner for history taking (asking for any symptoms or problems) and physical examination- will include blood pressure as well as checkup for skin, eye & hearing problems.
   - Blood tests: Hemogram (hemoglobin, total & differential white count, platelet count), sugar, kidney function (urea, creatinine, sodium, potassium), liver function (bilirubin, SGOT, SGPT, alkaline phosphatase), TSH (thyroid function), lipid profile (total, LDL and HDL cholesterol, triglyceride), vitamin D.  All these tests together need only 10 ml of blood and can be done in a day on newer machines; it may be called "single syringe blood screen"! (even though vacutainers have replaced syringes for blood sampling at most places)
   - Urine examination: albumin, sugar & microscopic examination
   - ECG
   - Chest X-ray every 5 years
   - for women: PAP smear, mammography

Other tests to be considered:

- colonoscopy
- bone density
- prostate specific antigen is not recommended; fecal occult blood is generally indicated if any anemia is found; I am not sure what test is done for bladder cancer screening apart from urine examination mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

According to the websites bellow, it´s a good idea to do the following tests annually at age 50 and beyond (beware of false positives, which "could trigger a cascade of even more tests, only to discover in the end that you had nothing wrong with you"):

> 1. Blood pressure if your blood pressure is borderline high.
> 2. Skin cancer screening ("It’s important to check your own skin, preferably once a month")
> 3. Eye exam and vision screening (every 2 years until age 60 and then yearly after that)
> 4. Vitamin D test
> 5. Fecal occult blood test (FOBT)
> 6. Thyroid test
> 7. Prostate cancer screening ("Screening should be done yearly for men whose PSA level is 2.5 ng/mL or higher, the decision should be made after getting information about the uncertainties, risks, and potential benefits of prostate cancer screening but men without symptoms of prostate cancer who do not have a 10-year life expectancy should not be offered testing" according to the American Cancer Association; but the  U.S. Preventive Services Task Force "recommends against PSA-based screening")
> 8. Testicular exam (The American Cancer Society recommends a testicular exam as part of a routine cancer-related checkup)
> 9. For women only: Pelvic exam
> 10. For women only: Breast exam and mammogram

If you have certain peculiarities or high risks other tests should be perform annually as well.

Information was gathered from the following websites:

http://www.webmd.com/healthy-aging/guide/milestone-medical-tests-50

https://www.caring.com/articles/medical-tests-men-should-have

http://www.webmd.com/hypertension-high-blood-pressure/guide/diastolic-and-systolic-blood-pressure-know-your-numbers?page=2#1

http://www.cancer.org/cancer/skincancer-melanoma/moreinformation/skincancerpreventionandearlydetection/skin-cancer-prevention-and-early-detection-skin-exams

http://www.webmd.com/osteoporosis/guide/who-needs-bone-density-testing

http://www.cancer.org/cancer/prostatecancer/moreinformation/prostatecancerearlydetection/prostate-cancer-early-detection-acs-recommendations

http://www.uspreventiveservicestaskforce.org/Page/Document/UpdateSummaryFinal/prostate-cancer-screening

http://www.cancer.org/healthy/toolsandcalculators/remind-me?_ga=1.240642179.1226571050.1444671502

Comment: It will help if you can mention if these should be done annually / 5 yearly etc?

Comment: I think much of this answer is wrong, but will only refute one aspect to start: prostate cancer screening is not recommended every year even by the [American Cancer Society](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/prostatecancer/moreinformation/prostatecancerearlydetection/prostate-cancer-early-detection-acs-recommendations). It's important to choose your sources carefully.

Comment: After my last pap smear came back normal, my doctor told me [I wouldn't need another one for three years](http://www.acog.org/~/media/districts/district%20ii/pdfs/uspstf_cervical_ca_screening_guidelines.pdf). Is she giving me bad advice? (In other words, there's a pattern here.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the tests and why they might be needed? Or are you merely parroting something you found on a website with no rationale behind it?

Comment: "...humans are not perfect, keeping up to date of myriad of conditions might be difficult, the medical science keeps evolving" (etc.) are not valid reasons with which to defend an erroneous answer. The problems with *this answer* don't lie with confused or reluctant medical professionals or the peculiarities of their patients. The problem is that either bad sources were quoted, or good ones misquoted. That will be a problem on this site.